# How to reuse wildcard parameter in cloud function trigger?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

How to reuse same wildcard parameter in cloud function trigger?

For example I want trigger only on: `‘/rootCollection/{docID}/{docID}/{doc}’`. I only want function trigger if doc is create in subcollection with same name as parent doc (`{docID}`).

I not want trigger if doc is create in other subcollection in doc `{docID}`.

So I have try use:

```
functions.firestore.document(‘/rootCollection/{docID}/{docID}/{doc}’)
```

But this give error when deploy.

If I change wildcard name for example to `{docIDCollection}` it work:

```
exports.exampleFunction = functions.firestore.document(‘/rootCollection/{docID}/{docIDCollection}/{doc}’)
.onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
```

But the function trigger when any doc is create in any subcollection in doc `{docID}`. Even if subcollection not have same name as parent doc. I no want this.

How to make third param same as second wildcard so function only trigger for subcollection with ID: `{docID}`?

Anyone help?

Comment: If you see an error with something you're trying to do, your question to show the error.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to validate what you're trying to do in the path of your Cloud Functions. Each parameter name in the path must be unique.

You will instead have to let de function trigger on more writes, and then ignore the ones on different subcollections in your code by comparing the named parameters.

```
exports.exampleFunction = functions.firestore.document(‘/rootCollection/{docID}/{docIDCollection}/{doc}’)
.onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
  if (context.params.docID == context.params.doc) {
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks! But is this efficient?

Comment: As said, you'll have to trigger on more writes. But it's the only way I can think of to implement your requirement.